# Is it possible to use a single UIView across multiple UIViewControllers?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have 6 UIViewControllers in my app at the moment, and while they are all different, they should all share the same custom toolbar at the top, as well as a drawer which is opened/closed by a button on said toolbar. The "toolbar" and "drawer" are both UIViews with some stuff inside. Is it possible to use the same UIView objects for all 6 of my UIViewControllers? Or do I have to copy the constraints, segues, controller code, etc for the toolbar and drawer for each UIViewController that I have in my app?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [containerView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontrollercontexttransitioning/1622045-containerview).

You can add containerViews in each of your ViewControllers and embed your UIView.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do in this situation is make a view controller that embeds a child view controller. On this view controller, you would set up your toolbar and drawer, then you would have a Container View that can embed a navigation controller which would manage all your other view controllers. On a storyboard, you can right-click and drag from a Container View to another controller to embed it.